# Google Actions: Account linking sends GET request to token URL

Tags: actions-on-google

I have some problems with the Account Linking for Google Actions:

I have implemented the OAuth2 steps described in the documentation by Google. I have implemented my OAuth2 server and tested it via Postman and am able to get an access token as expected.

If I try to authenticate from the Google Home app by adding the service to my account, I get taken to my authorization form, the authorization works fine and responds with an authorization code to Google's redirect URI as it is supposed to do. However Googles return URI says 'Account linking failed' and then I get a message in the Google Home app : 'Can't update the settings. Check your connection'.

Another strange thing that I've see from my logging of my Token URL script: I can see an incoming GET request from Google to my Token URL instead of a POST request with the required data as mentioned in the Google documentation. So even though the message 'Account linking failed' appears, it seems that Google is calling my token URL, but with a GET instead of a POST.

These are the logs of the requests to the token URL:

REQUEST FROM POSTMAN (testing software) > OK

```
__SERVER
Array
(
    [USER] => www-data
    [HOME] => /var/www
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => */*
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => PostmanRuntime/7.6.1
    [HTTP_POSTMAN_TOKEN] => f85664e2-7d38-4511-9519-cddda3feec06
    [HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL] => no-cache
    [HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    [HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH] => 145
    [HTTP_CONNECTION] => close
    [HTTP_HOST] => 127.0.0.1
    [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
    [SERVER_NAME] => _
    [SERVER_PORT] => 80
    [SERVER_ADDR] => 127.0.0.1
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 38622
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 127.0.0.1
    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => nginx/1.12.2
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [REQUEST_SCHEME] => http
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.0
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => [******]
    [DOCUMENT_URI] => /google/token/index.php
    [REQUEST_URI] => /google/token/
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /google/token/index.php
    [CONTENT_LENGTH] => 145
    [CONTENT_TYPE] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => POST
    [QUERY_STRING] =>
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => [******]
    [FCGI_ROLE] => RESPONDER
    [PHP_SELF] => /google/token/index.php
    [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1553765980.9273
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1553765980
)
__POST
Array
(
    [client_id] => [******]
    [client_secret] => [******]
    [grant_type] => authorization_code
    [code] => [******]
)
```

REQUEST RECEIVED WHEN TESTING WITH GOOGLE HOME APP on smartphone > NOT OK

```
__SERVER
Array
(
    [USER] => www-data
    [HOME] => /var/www
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip,deflate,br
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => OpenAuth
    [HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    [HTTP_CONNECTION] => close
    [HTTP_HOST] => 127.0.0.1
    [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
    [SERVER_NAME] => _
    [SERVER_PORT] => 80
    [SERVER_ADDR] => 127.0.0.1
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 46184
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 127.0.0.1
    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => nginx/1.12.2
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [REQUEST_SCHEME] => http
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.0
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => [******]
    [DOCUMENT_URI] => /google/token/index.php
    [REQUEST_URI] => /google/token/
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /google/token/index.php
    [CONTENT_LENGTH] =>
    [CONTENT_TYPE] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [QUERY_STRING] =>
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => [******]
    [FCGI_ROLE] => RESPONDER
    [PHP_SELF] => /google/token/index.php
    [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1553767309.7797
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1553767309
)
__REQUEST
Array
(
)
__POST
Array
(
)
__GET
Array
(
)
-------------------------
__ANSWER
400: invalid grant
```

[Configuration in Actions Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ybxS.png)

Comment: koenvi welcome. Please read [how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ask a good question in the help center.

Comment: Include your code, screenshots or layoutfile and logcat. This will help you get a quicker response. Also follow the How To Ask guide before posting a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask If your question does not fit into the How To Ask guideline, you can try beginner programming forums and groups which will help you better than SO. If you've got precise technical problems with your code then post it on SO. If you do not follow the SO questions guideline your question might be downvoted or closed with no gain or response. You can edit your question and improve it

Comment: This seems odd for a couple of reasons. If possible, I would suggest updating your question (which is otherwise quite good, no matter what the previous commenters have said) with a screen shot of the Action Console where you have configured account linking (masking any sensitive information) and the logs from the GET that is happening against your Token URL (again, mask specific sensitive info). If you can get logs (either browser or server) from the auth exchange, that would be good as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem seemed to be caused by the redirect of / to /index.php without the POST values.

Fixed it by changing my URLs in the Actions Console to /index.php and now the linking works fine.